# How fast should I set the metronome for agitato?

Tags: tempo, march

What would the numeric tempo range be for a march marked "agitato"?

Comment: That will vary on the piece so much that I am voting to close.  With a more specific question, I would vote to re-open.

Comment: An "agitato" tempo is fast, at least allegro.  The third movement of Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata is marked "Presto agitato" for example.  If your piece is marked "tempo agitato" it will mean a fast tempo, but you don't have more than that to go on beyond Mark Lutton's explanation.

Comment: Lol Bob I thought of exactly that piece when I wrote my answer.

Comment: That is in middle of a piece, here on the beginning  it says only agitato. I know that this is a march  from the title.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the manuscripts the title of this is  "battle music" sorry again. Does this change something?

Answer (score 3):

Agitato is an indication of character not speed. As Mark points out it means agitated or aggressive but that does not mean that it is inherently fast.

You have the third movement from the Moonlight Sonata that is Presto Agitato

This song from the soundtrack of Interview with the Vampire shows a piece that is Allegro Agitato just to illustrate that the mere fact that there is an indcation of Agitato does not necessarily mean fast.

Answer (score 1):

"Agitato" is not exactly a speed.  It means "agitated" and generally means that the speed will be faster than normal -- it's more a relative speed than an absolute speed.  But really it's more of a mood or feeling than a speed.

A typical tempo for a standard parade march is 112. I can picture a band marching to that tempo in a Fourth of July parade, but I'm having trouble picturing a band marching "agitatedly".  Maybe the enemy is advancing directly behind them?

If that were the case I guess they would be doing a Quick March.  Try 140 bpm which is typical Quick March tempo and see how that works.

Comment: I tried 140 it's to fast, even 130 is not ideal. I put it to 124.

Comment: Whatever speed works best.